Getting an empty object in data for updates
Im working on updating a document in my mongodb, the document has a field, which is an object that has other fields attached to it, I have 1 field i want to update, the others should stay the same, however when i update the one field, it removes all other fields from the document, I read in a different SO article that i need to use dot notation for the specific field i want to update. So im working on that, however i have an interesting issue in that, when i create the dot notated field, all it does is return an empty object to the backend, even though if i console log it right before sending it, its correct.. i dont know why im getting an empty object.
Here is the onFinish handler, this is whats fired off when the form is submitted:
const onFinish = () => {
    const data =
      targetKeys
        .map(
          (key) => dataSource.find((item) => item.key === key)?.name
        )
        .filter((name) => name !== undefined) || [];

    const formData = {
      'baseObject.fieldToUpdate': data,
    };

    console.log('formData:', formData); // Log the request body

    updateData({
      url: `/.../.../${id}`,
      formData,
    });
  };

the information thats returned for data is an array of string values, so it looks similar to this: [ 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', ...nth ] again, when i console log the value before sending it to the action to send to the backend, the object is correct.. but all the backend receives is a blank object.
its worthwhile to note that if i structure the data like so, it also shows up in the req.body on the server, but, doing it like this means that it removes all other information:
{
    baseObject: {
       fieldToUpdate: data
    }
}

